# Trouble when trying to extend class

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, compiler-errors

I am writing a program which will take a list of temps and days and implement the list using an array of object. each object will store the temp(double) and day(string). then we need to sort the objects and output them.  I created my first class(DailyTemperature) with the two variables, get/set methods, and a constructor.  Now when I go to create my second class(DailyTemperatureList) with the ArrayList in it I get an error when trying to add to the list the error says 
"no suitable method found for add(java.lang.String,double) method java.util.ArrayList.add(int,DailyTemperature) is not applicable (actual argument java.lang.String cannot be converted to int by method invocation conversion) method java.util.ArrayList.add(DailyTemperature) is not applicable actualy and formal lists differ in length.

I assume its because I am trying to use variables from the DailyTemperature class.but when i extend it i get an error saying constructor DailyTemperature in class DailyTemperature cannot be applied to given types. I am not sure why. Am i not supposed to be extending and perhaps do something else?

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DailyTemperature 
{
     //variables
    private double temperature;
    private String day;

    //getTemp & setTemp methods
    public double getTemp()
    {
      return temperature;
    }

    public void setTemp(double newTemp)
    {
      temperature = newTemp;
    }

    //getDay & setTEmp methods
    public String getDay()
    {
      return day;
    }

    public void setDay(String newDay)
    {
      day = newDay;
    }


    public DailyTemperature(String day, double temperature) {

      this.day = day;
      this.temperature = temperature;
    }


}



import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DailyTemperatureList extends DailyTemperature
{
    public static void main (String [] args) {


    ArrayList<DailyTemperature> dailytemps = new ArrayList<DailyTemperature>();

    dailytemps.add("Mon", 78.1);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not have DailyTemperatureList extend DailyTemperature. That's not what inheritance is for since a collection of something is not a something. Your inheritance doesn't pass the "is-a" test; for instance a college class of students is not a more specific concept of an individual student. Instead have the first class contain an ArrayList of the second class, or  `ArrayList<DailyTemperature>`.

Also, the ArrayList has an add method that accepts one parameter, here your DailyTemperature object, or one that accepts an int and an object, but not a String and an object.

I would also make DailyTemperature implement the `Comparable<DailyTemperature>` interface so that a List of this can be sorted easily.

Comment: how do I implement the comparable<DailyTemperature> interface?

so in the DailyTemperatureList class would using this line "dailytemps.add(new DailyTemperature("Mon", 78.1));" add elements to the list that I could then sort?

Comment: @SophiaAli implementing `Comparable` is useful, but you should make you code work first. To implement `Comparable<DailyTemperature>`, `DailyTemperature` needs to declare it implements it, and it needs to implement `int compareTo(DailyTemperature)` as defined by [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). Read about implementing interfaces from the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/usinginterface.html).

Answer (score 2):

`dailytemps` is an `ArrayList` of`DailyTemperature`. So when adding to it, you need to add an instance of `DailyTemperature`:

```
dailytemps.add(new DailyTemperature("Mon", 78.1));
```

As currently implemented, `DailyTemperatureList` does not need to extend `DailyTemperature`.

Comment: The problems you get when extending `DailyTemperature` come from the need to explicitly call the constructor of the parent class when the parent class does not have no-argument constructor. You'd need to have a constructor that calls `super(String, double)`, but since `DailyTemperatureList` should not extend `DailyTemperature` in the first place, that's a bit academic.

Comment: I added dailytemps.add(new DailyTemperature("Mon", 78.1)); for all 5 days. Are the days/temperatures saved in an array as well or do I need to create an array linking it the list?

Comment: @SophiaAli I don't know where or why you'd need an array. `ArrayList` (ie. dailytemps) uses internally an array to store the contents, it just is not exposed by the interface. If you *really* need an array, you can get use the the [toArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T[]%29) method of the list.